# Python CSV File Row Compare

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, compare

I have a csv file where each row looks like:

```
OrderedDict([('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value2'), ('key3', 'value3'), ('key4', 'value4'), ('key5', 'value5')])
```

I want to compare two keys on adjacent rows to find matches and store those rows (dicts) to a list.

```
#if (key1 and key2) in row[i+1] == row[i]
            #append row[i] and row[i+1] to a new match list; becomes a list of dicts
#else go to next row
```

I am struggling to understand how to reference a row in python. I know enumerate will give me an index number for each row but it's not clear to me how, or if, I can use it as a reference. Itertools seems like it would be helpful but not sure how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you csv file is like this as you have mention in question

```
key1, key2 ,...
val11, val12 ,..
val21, val22 ,..
```

now code if

```
  with open('test.csv','r') as f:
        csv_lst = list(csv.DictReader(f))  # if your csv is large than this can be problem

        for first_row,next_row in zip(csv_lst,csv_lst[1:]):
            print("Now you have both row with dictionary you can apply your logic ")
```

python way to parallel iteration is using `zip` so i converted all csv data in list then `zip(csv_list, csv_list[1:])` first parameter mean starting csc_list from beginning like 0 and other  parameter mean starting `csv_list` form 1 so you will have `0 1, 1 2,2 3`  iteration of list.

Comment: I haven't finished testing, but this approach looks like it will work. Thanks for the explanation too. I wouldn't have understood how it works just by looking at the code.

Comment: I finished testing and this approach works.

Comment: I find that f, s are already dicts so statements  first_row = dict(f) and next_row = dict(s) are not needed. s and f can be used directly.

Comment: @Duncan        you are right so i have edited

Answer (score 0):

By definition, keys in dictionaries are unique. So comparing the keys of 2 'rows' is unlikely to work. This solution uses pandas.

Lets say 'Sample_data.csv' contains these rows (with 'keys' as first column):

keys, values

A, 1

B, 2

C, 3

C, 33

D, 4

E, 5

E, 55

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = pd.read_table('sample_data.csv', sep=',')  # imports data into dataframe
outdata = (data1[['keys']]==data1[['keys']].shift()).any(axis=1)   # bool of rows to capture
data2 = data1.loc[outdata | outdata.shift(-1),]   # captured rows and one before it, includes all columns
data2
```

output:

| index | keys | values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | C | 3 |
| 3 | C | 33 |
| 5 | E | 5 |
| 6 | E | 55 |